# How to compile multiple files together with ml in assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, global-variables

I'm working in x86 assembly in 16bits.
I have three files that need to share 'variables between them' - basically, the data segment. When I compile them, as in the following:

```
ml file1.asm,file2.asm,file3.asm io.lib
```

They cannot access each other's variables
How do I share a data segment, and thus variables between the files?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just about like in C, you create a header (usually given the extension ".inc") that contains external declarations for what's contained in another file, as in:

```
;file def_data.asm:
.586P
.model flat, c

.data
     myword dd ?

end 

; file def_data.inc:
externdef myword:dword

; file use_data.asm:
.586P
.model flat, c

include def_data.inc

.code
myproc proc
    mov eax, myword
myproc endp
    end
```

Comment: thank you. how would I go about doing such a thing for a proc?

Comment: Sorry -- I didn't notice this until you asked it as a separate question. Hopefully that answer helped...

Answer (score 5):

This looks relevent: [The PUBLIC, EXTERN, and EXTRN Directives](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_8/CH08-10.html#HEADING10-56) and [The EXTERNDEF Directive](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_8/CH08-10.html#HEADING10-109).